Assigndifferent paletes to different geoms but same scale
For example
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = Species, fill = Species), method = "lm", se = FALSE)


Is there some way to assign a palette (for example through scale_color_discrete) to points and a different paler to the lines produced by geom_smooth?
Thank you!

Have you looked into the {ggnewscale} package?

Thanks! I didn't know it. Wondeful!

There isn't a very clean way to do this within ggplot2, but there is a package called ggnewscale that will help.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = 1) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = Species), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = 2)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'


Created on 2024-07-06 with reprex v2.1.1
Another solution without any new packages, is just changing the color to fill and giving the points a shape.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+
  geom_smooth(aes(color = Species), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species), shape = 21, size = 3, colour="transparent") +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = 2) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 1) 
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'


Created on 2024-07-06 with reprex v2.1.1

Thanks! Let's keep the first solution, which is more general. The second is just a trick which solves this particular example but cannot be applied to the actual ggplot I am dealing with.
